# C++ strptime giving wrong results

Tags: c++, time, strptime

I'm parsing a file containing strings formatted as `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`. I'm trying to read them and convert them to Unix timestamps, using the following code :

```
tm tm;
cout << datestr << endl;
strptime(str.c_str(), "&d/&m/&Y %H:&M:&S", &tm);
cout << tm.tm_year << " " << tm.tm_mon << " " << tm.tm_mday << " " << tm.tm_hour << " " << tm.tm_min << " " << tm.tm_sec << " " << endl;
timestamp = mktime(&tm);
```

This is what happens when I run the program :

```
24/01/2014 00:04:42
4 6 31 4 1 8
```

Where does the problem come from? I also noted that it seems to give the same output regardless of the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), the conversion specifiers use the `%` character, rather than the `&` you have used.

Thus, the following code should be used:

```
strptime(str.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
```

Comment: Thank you... Not sure how I could miss something this obvious